# pandas filter large dataframe and order by a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe as follows:

```
master_df

             result   item
0            5        id13
1            6        id23432
2            3        id2832
3            4        id9823
......
84376253     7        id9632
```

And another smaller dataframe as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'item' : ['id9632', 'id13', 'id2832', 'id2342']})
```

How can I extract the relevant elements from `master_df.result` to match with `df.item` so I can achieve the following:

```
df = df.assign(result=list_of_results_in_order)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) also:

```
df = df.merge(master_df, on='item', how='left)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think need [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
#for Series
s = master_df.loc[master_df['item'].isin(df['item']),'result']
print (s)
0           5
2           3
84376253    7
Name: result, dtype: int64

#for list
L = master_df.loc[master_df['item'].isin(df['item']),'result'].tolist()
print (L)
[5, 3, 7]

#for DataFrame
df1 = master_df[master_df['item'].isin(df['item'])]
print (df1)
          result    item
0              5    id13
2              3  id2832
84376253       7  id9632
```